# In ionic, how to detect incoming call

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

When an ionic app is open, how to detect for a incoming call and get the number. We would like to have this feature for both ios and android.

Have searched for this feature, the answers we found seems outdated.

Comment: check this out : http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/24/how-to-get-notified-during-an-incoming-call-and-get-that-number-inside-your-program-in-android/

Comment: Question said ionic. @AndiGeeky

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a plugin for this at https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap

Do know that this only works with Android and not iOS because apps are sandboxed in iOS.

Alternatively, seeing as its an ionic app, you could use the document listeners "pause" event as that gets called when calls come in.