# How to implement Video calling in Ionic Web application?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a requirement for one to one video calling in web application. I implemented this web app by using the Ionic framework. I am unable to find any library for video calls for the web. All libraries that we have been working for Android and Ios, not for the web.

Can any please help me with how to implement video calling in Ionic web application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: openVido is a video call library

Comment: use `WebRTC` its an open source audio video communication.  https://webrtc.org/

Answer (score 2):

For camera you need to use native module for this.

Here is the documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera

But on incoming call, it seems does not work well.

Here is the information:
[In ionic, how to detect incoming call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175583/in-ionic-how-to-detect-incoming-call)

You might can develop native plugin with your own.

Comment: Hi Almas Dusal, Thank you for your replay. Is the plugin you mentioned will work for Ionic Web application?

Comment: I didn't tried it on browser. But there is a written "Supported Platforms:  Android, Browser, iOS, Windows" on the module page.